Find $a$ so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow7}\left(\frac{18-\left\lfloor1-x\right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor x-3a\right\rfloor}\right)$ exists
Find $a$ so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow7}\left(\frac{18-\left\lfloor1-x\right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor x-3a\right\rfloor}\right)$ exists
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function
MY attempt :-
$\lim_{x\rightarrow7^+}\left(\frac{18+7}{\left\lfloor7-3a\right\rfloor}\right)$
$\lim_{x\rightarrow7^-}\left(\frac{18+6}{\left\lfloor7-3a\right\rfloor}\right)$
$\lim_{x\rightarrow7^+}\frac{25}{\left\lfloor7-3a\right\rfloor}=\lim_{x\rightarrow7^-}\frac{24}{\left\lfloor7-3a\right\rfloor}$
now what?
Edit :- By trial and error I found the answer is $-6$. Is there any other way to approach this?
Edit 2 :-  thanks to satyam singh and Jyrki Lahtone  for the hints , this is my working based on that
$25\lfloor{7^{-}-3a}\rfloor=24 \lfloor{7^+ -3a}\rfloor$
$\lfloor{7^{-}-3}\rfloor=3$
$\lfloor{7^{-}-6}\rfloor=0$
$\lfloor{7^{-}-9}\rfloor=-3$
and so on, so just as Jyrki Lahtonen mentioned
$\lim_{x\to7-}[x-3a]=6-3a$
now to try to find a similar pattern for
$\lim_{x\to7^+}[x-3a]$
$\lfloor7^+ -3 \rfloor=4$
$\lfloor7^+ -6 \rfloor=1$
$\lfloor7^+ -9 \rfloor=-2$
which is $7-3a$
so I have to solve
$27\left(7-3a\right)=24\left(6-3a\right)$
which gives $a=-6$

I believe that, when $a$ equals $5$, $53145$ or even $11557684332255884688855554444$, the limit will exist :-)

If $3a$ happens to be an integer, you have $\lim_{x\to7-}[x-3a]=6-3a,$ right?

There is a mistake in this step

$\lim_{x\rightarrow7^+}\frac{25}{\left[7-3a\right]}=\lim_{x\rightarrow7^-}\frac{24}{\left[7-3a\right]}$

It should be

$ \frac{25}{\left[7^+-3a\right]}=\frac{24}{\left[7^--3a\right]}$

I gave you a hint. You can continue from here.
